# cmd not recognizing Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cmd

I installed "java 8" software after downloading ".war" for Jenkins. In cmd, I navigated to ".war" location, then I tried to invoke Jenkins but it shows me 0 output:

[image: cmd line text]

I tried two ways to invoke "jenkins" in cmd but **no use**:

```
java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=9090
```

(or)

```
java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=8080
```

Comment: What do you get from `java -version`

Comment: It shows me same **0** blank output.

Comment: I would uninstall then reinstall Java. Make sure you have the right version to run jenkins.war